# How to make the drawable part of the textview clickable?

Tags: android, xml, textview

I have a `textview` with an attribute `drawable_right` as shown below in the xml file. I want to make only this drawable clickable, so that when the user click the drawable part of the `textview` a certain aktion occure. Also i have checked some questions on stackoverflow but most of them are using `spannable` which needs a start and end parameters to be specified, and in my case, there are no start nor end to provide.

Is there any way to make the drawable part of the `TextView` clickable?
XML:

```
<TextView
 ....
 ....
 android:clickable = "true"
 android:drawable_right = "@drawable/accept"/>
```

Comment: As I know, you can't do that. It's better to put a Button there instead a drawable and put action for that

Comment: delimiter? what delimiter?

Comment: @pskink when you use spannable you have to specify where your textview for an example you want it to be clickable, so you have to specify characters between which your view is clickable. that's why i called them delimiter

Comment: when you use Spannable you use setSpan which has two ints: "start" and "stop" parameters

Comment: yes true, that's what i ment by delimiters, i would correct that. thanks for informing

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom view extending LinearLayout like this:

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout{
    public CustomView(Context context){
        ImageView mImageView = new ImageView(context);
        TextView mTextView = new TExtView(context);

        addView(mImageView);
        addView(mTextView);
    }

    public void setImageClickListener(OnClickListener mOnClickListener){
        mImageView.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    }

    (....)
}
```

More on custom views:
http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html